# swagger return `Whitelabel Error Page` for url `../swagger-ui.html`

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I followed this link: [a Chinese introduction article](https://developer.ibm.com/zh/technologies/spring/articles/j-using-swagger-in-a-spring-boot-project/), according to it, I only need to add the dependencies in `pom.xml`. (`./v2/api-docs` has been always working.)

It used to work, but today it breaks.

my swagger dependencies in `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using spring boot 2.3.3, and swagger 2.9.2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `SwaggerConfig.java`,

add below codes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    
    ...

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // 解决静态资源无法访问
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        // 解决swagger无法访问
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        // 解决swagger的js文件无法访问
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
```

Comment: Th is the hard way to do it, spring boot has a configuration property, which you can just use. instead of hard coding stuff.

Comment: @zatef would you mind explain it in detail and response this question as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Done, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of spring boot, this can be achieved with a property:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/,classpath:/static/vendor/,classpath:/static/custom/
```

Also, make sure you configure SpringSecurity class to accept requests to this resources

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
{
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers( "/static/**","/resources/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**");

}
```